# Laravel envelope MIX_VAR displaying wrong value

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get ENV variable from JS in laravel, but the value is wrong.

To prevent duplicates I am using this syntax:

`APP_ENV=development
 MIX_APP_ENV="${APP_ENV}"`

And in `console.log(process.env.APP_ENV)` it gives me ${APP_ENV} in browser. It doesn't matter if I remove the double quotes from ENV file.

I cleared cache and restarted NPM run watch.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: You need to use it as `process.env.MIX_APP_ENV`

Comment: @apokryfos I added console.log(process.env.MIX_APP_ENV) and in console I get `${APP_ENV}`

Comment: Remove the double quotes in your .env file around `${APP_ENV}`

Comment: @apokryfos As I stated in my post, it does not make any difference

Comment: What version of laravel and mix are you using?

Comment: @apokryfos "laravel-mix": "^4.1.4"